# Getting smtpException when attemping to send mail C#

Tags: c#, mono, smtpclient

I'm trying to send an email through SmtpClient using this code

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***@gmail.com", "password"),
            EnableSsl = true,
        };
        client.Send("***@gmail.com", "***@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
```

What I'm getting is smtpException "Message could not be sent".

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Message could not be sent. ---> System.Exception:Connectionclosed at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Read () [0x000f9] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-mono-
```

I'm using Mono on Mac (OSX 10.9.2)

My credentials and host/port are correct.
Maybe I need to enable it through my gmail account somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about the port ? I'm using gmail for sending emails and I use port 587.

Comment: same smtpException using port 587

Comment: Your code looks fine; it might be worth checking your firewall isn't preventing the connection. You say your credentials are definitely correct, but you've probably checked that by logging into gmail via the web; that obviously doesn't use the same port as connecting via SMTP in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
           {
               Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
               Port = 587,
               EnableSsl = true,
               DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
               UseDefaultCredentials = false,
               Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
           };
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                     {
                         Subject = subject,
                         Body = body
                     })
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Not working. same smtpException. Could the problem be Mono SDK?

Comment: @NivNavick What is your exception?

Comment: Seems to work on visual studio. The problem is MONO SDK. Thanks!

Comment: You could try using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead - it's a bit more robust than Mono's implementation of System.Net.Mail and works on Windows, Mac and Linux.